# Regex: Don't urlify links that were code-prettified before

Tags: javascript, html, regex

I have a regex that first prettifies any text between back-ticks (``) as code. And then I use another regex that detects urls and generates anchor tag. Just like stackoverflow's editor. The problem is I don't want to urlify the links in code-prettified part.

For example the first url in the following example should be urlified but the second one shouldn't:

To generate a link to http://stackoverflow.com you should write

`<a href="http://stackoverflow.com">StackOverflow</a>`

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! You forgot to add your code. Without it, this question is too broad. Please check out [How to Ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask), and take the [tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour).